# Multi-thread file access (locking control)

Tags: c#, file, deadlock, locks

i have two programs working on the same file
i want the first program to check regularly on the file, and if any changes are made operate on the file and empty it.
the other program writes to the file.
the problem occurs when the second program tries to write on the file because it's used from the first one
is there an (if there's any implemented C# program would be even better) algorithm to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the problem"?

Comment: @GETah I guess he means "lock" problem.

Comment: do you have a control over the 'other program'

Comment: @Muaaz Sorry to be picky, but you have a concurrency issue, which, based on your description, has nothing to do with multi-thread. I'm aware of being a bit pedantic, but using "multi-thread" in your title could be misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if file has changed you might first of all check its timestamp. In pseudo code, you might try something like this in the monitoring program:

```
try {
  if(FileTimeStampHasChanged(FileName)) {
    //Attempt to do something with the file
  }
}
catch {
  // Handle or ignore the exception if you can't open the file (maybe the other application hasn't finished writing). You can always retry later.
}
```

However, I would strongly recommend a different approach altogether. Here are the options I'd suggest.

1. If you can alter the writing program, let it write to a temporary file (e.g. *output.$$$*) and let it rename it as soon as it's done writing. Renaming is instantaneous and doesn't cause any locking. This is, in my experience, one of the best simple solutions for concurrent access.
2. If you **cannot** alter the writing program, then modify the reading one. Using the logic I described in point 1, let it try to rename the file to read and work on the renamed copy. If the rename fails, then it means that the writer isn't done, and an attempt can be done later.
3. If you cannot alter any of the programs, then you can make your own "traffic warden" application to implement point 1. It requires more work, but it's still doable. Here's how:

   - Configure the Writer to write into a folder, e.g. "Output".
   - Configure the Reader to read from another folder, e.g. "Input".
   - Write your Traffic Warden so that it monitors Output folder and, when the file changes, it moves it to Input folder. Moving is instantaneous as well (it's practically the same operation as renaming).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for opening file in both programs with [FileShare.Write or ReadWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) using [FileStream constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7db28s3c.aspx).

If you open file this way both will be able to write. Note that you will have to manually implement some synchronization mechanism between 2 programs so they don't overwrite each others data.

Closing file after each write and waiting for file becoming unlocked when opening it may be easier option depending on access pattern.

Note that if you don't have control over one of the programs your only option is to simply wait till it is done with file in your program (you can force other program to close file handle, but you just don't want to do that as it will likely corrupt data).

Comment: That might solve the concurrency issue, but we don't know what the file contains. If it's a text file, being able to read it while it's written could be worse than the lock issue he's experiencing.

Comment: I tried to put it as "have to manually implement some synchronization" but failed... Feel free to merge with your answer if you want.

Comment: I don't think it's needed, it's actually good that you proposed a solution to access the same files at the same time. :)