# Good practice for parallel tasks in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have one python script which is generating data and one which is training a neural network with tensorflow and keras on this data. Both need an instance of the neural network.

Since I haven't set the flag "allow growth" each process takes the full GPU memory. Therefore I simply give each process it's own GPU. (Maybe not a good solution for people with only one GPU... yet another unsolved problem)

The actual problem is as follow: Both instances need access to the networks weights file. I recently had a bunch of crashes because both processes tried to access the weights. A flag or something similar should stop each process from accessing it, whilst the other process is accessing. Hopefully this doesn't create a bottle neck.
I tried to come up with a solution like semaphores in C, but today I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195394/8710430) in stack-exchange.

The idea with renaming seems quite simple and effective to me. Is this good practice in my case? I'll just create the weight file with my own function

```
self.model.save_weights(filepath='weights.h5$$$')
```

in the learning process, rename them after saving with

```
os.rename('weights.h5$$$', 'weights.h5')
```

and load them in my data generating process with function

```
self.model.load_weights(filepath='weights.h5')
```

?

Will this renaming overwrite the old file? And what happens if the other process is currently loading? I would appreciate other ideas how I could multithread / multiprocess my script. Just realized that generating data, learn, generating data,... in a sequential script is not really performant.

EDIT 1: Forgot to mention that the weights are stored in a .h5 file by keras' save function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` module has a [`RLock`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.RLock) class that you can use to regulate access to a sharded resource. *This also works for files if you remember to acquire the lock before reading and writing and release it afterwards.* Using a lock implies that some of the time one of the processes cannot read or write the file. How much of a problem this is depends on how much both processes have to access the file.

Note that for this to work, one of the scripts has to start the other script as a `Process` *after* creating the lock.

If the weights are a Python data structure, you could put that under control of a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). That will manage access to the objects under its control for you. *Note that a `Manager` is not meant for use with files, just in-memory objects*.

Additionally on UNIX-like operating systems Python has [`os.lockf`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.lockf) to lock (part of) a file. Note that this is an *advisory* lock only. That is, if another process calls `lockf`, the return value indicates that the file is already locked. It does not actually prevent you from reading the file.

**Note:**
Files can be read and written. *Only* when two processes are *reading* the same file (read/read) does this work well. Every other combination (read/write, write/read, write/write) can and eventually will result in undefined behavior and data corruption.

**Note2:**
Another possible solution involves inter process communication.
Process 1 writes a new h5 file (with a random filename), closes it, and then sends a message (using a [`Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) or `Queue` to Process 2 "I've written a new parameter file \path\to\file".
Process 2 then reads the file and deletes it. This can work both ways but requires that both processes check for and process messages every so often. This prevents file corruption because the writing process only notifies the reading process *after* it has finished the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So RLock is similar to the semaphores in C right? Will this create an artificial bottleneck? What do you think about the renaming idea from the other post? It's mentioned that this works instantaneous which would be nice. The weight file is saved in a .h5 file. I quickly googled the manager combined with .h5 file which gave me this [link](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/examples/multiprocessing_example.py). The author mentions that using multiple processes will "results in undefined behavior". So this won't work in my case will it?

Comment: Thanks! So far I have the impression that looking it and waiting whilst saving is the only way.

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon You could also combine files with inter process communication. See **Note2**.

Comment: Thats a solution I thought about. I was not sure if I can do this because of the two processes assigned to two GPUs. Did I get your idea right? I'll create one process and try to assign one GPU, create the second process in the same file, assign another GPU and then let them communicate over a pipe about the weights file?

Starting two programs separately and let them communicated over a pipe is not possible right?

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon Using `multiprocessing.Pipe` indeed only works if one process starts the other. There are ways for unrelated processes to talk to each other. For example [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). But those are operating system dependant.